# Prove that for every formula in the first-order logic language $l$ there is a quantifier free formula($B$) that have the following property.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

T = {$\forall x \forall y\ x = y$}.For every formula $A$ in the language I'm going to find a quantifier free formula $B$  such that :$T\vdash (A\rightarrow B) \land (B\rightarrow A)$.
I think if we write the formula A in the form $Q1\ x1 ...Qn\ xn\ B$ ,$Q\in\{\forall , \exists\}$,then B that is quantifier free is the desired formula. if $m$ is a l-structural model such that $m \vDash T$ and $m\vDash A$ it is easy to prove that $m \vDash B$,note that $m\vDash T$ means that the world of the $m$ has at most one element.but the problem is when $m \vDash T$ nd $m \vDash B$ and the world of $m$ has no element and there is a existential quantifier in A,we cannot 
deduce that $m \vDash A$,where am I wrong?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is quite unclear ... first, do you mean $\forall x \forall y x=y$?  For that would indeed imply that any model has exactly one element.  Second, what are $A$ and $B$ supposed to be or do?  Because it is trivial to find $A$ and $B$ such that $T \vdash (A \rightarrow B) \land (A \rightarrow B)$ (I assume you want those parentheses there ...):  just make sure $A$ is identical or equivalent to $B$ .. for example let $A=B=P$ for some atomic statement $P$ ... but I am sure that's not what you are looking for ... so what are you looking for?

Comment: @Bram28 , I edited the question,  isn't it possible for the model to has no elements?

Comment: Most logic systems make the 'Assumption of Existential Import', which assumes that the domain always contains at least one element.  This is because if you assume that, all kinds of logical equivalences and implications and inferences hold that would not hold if the domain could be empty.  There are logics that don't make this assumption; they are called free logics.  But unless you are told that you are dealing with a free logic, you should be able to assume that the domain is never empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $T$ implies that there is exactly one object in the domain, you can take any formula $A$ and find formula $B$ by dropping all quantifiers, and by replacing all variables with a constant $a$.

For example, if

$$A = \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$$

then $$B = R(a,a)$$

This also works if the quantifiers are not all in front, e.g. if

$$A = \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow \exists y (Q(y) \land R(x,y)))$$

then

$$B = P(a) \rightarrow (Q(a) \land R(a,a))$$

Comment: I wasn't familiar with this assumption,Thank you so much.

Comment: @MAh2014 You're welcome! :)